# T-SQL: Convert XML to string without self-closing tags

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

We have a weirdo system we're integrating with which consumes XML, but it *does not* understand self-closing tags, so

```
<BOOKING>
  <BOOKINGID>56812</BOOKINGID>
  <PERSONCODE />
</BOOKING>
```

is beyond its capabilities.

If what I have is `declare @x xml`, how do I convert that `@x` to string *without* having self-closing tags:

```
<BOOKING>
  <BOOKINGID>56812</BOOKINGID>
  <PERSONCODE></PERSONCODE>
</BOOKING>
```

Comment: Is it acceptible to not include the empty elements at all, or are they required? Also, are you creating the XML output by concatenating strings, or by using [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107) on your queries?

Answer (score 4):

A workaround would be to add an unlikely value to your empty nodes using [insert (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx) and then [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) the value on your string representation.

```
declare @S nvarchar(max)

declare @XML xml = '
<BOOKING>
  <BOOKINGID>56812</BOOKINGID>
  <PERSONCODE />
</BOOKING>'

-- Add _ as value to all empty nodes
while @XML.exist('//*[.="" and count(*)=0]') = 1
  set @XML.modify('insert text{"_"} into (//*[.="" and count(*)= 0])[1]')

-- Cast to string and remove _ as value
set @S = replace(cast(@XML as nvarchar(max)), '>_<', '><')

select @S
```